# Python processes images, but overrides existing image and creates new images

Tags: python, image, opencv

I am trying to resize images and then store the images as img_resized.jpg

I am able to resize original files and save the resized images as img_resized.jpg, but when I run the program again: The original images in said folder stays the same, and the program resizes/changes the img_resized.jpg and also adds another img_resized_resized.jpg.

The extra img_resized_resized.jpg is acceptable atm since I have not made an if statement excluding existing files named _resiazed.jpg.

This is the code I've written so far. I expected the code to resize all images in said folder, and create new img_resized.jpg of all images in folder. But it alters some of the already resized images in folder. It does not change the originals.
How can i prevent the script from changing the img_resized.jpg files in folder while creating new files?

```
import cv2
import glob
import os


def img_reshape(img_file):
    image = cv2.imread(str(img_file), 1)
    resized_image = cv2.resize(image, (int(image.shape[1]/2), int(image.shape[0]/2)))
    file_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(img_file))[0]
    output_path = f"files\\sample_images\\{file_name}_resized.jpg"
    return cv2.imwrite(output_path, img=resized_image)


def main():

    for files in glob.glob("files\\sample_images\\*.jpg"):
        img_reshape(files)

main()
```

Comment: indentation needs correcting for the code to work.

Comment: What do you suppose the `*.jpg` means? You're writing the output also as JPEGs, into the same directory you read from.

Comment: How did you get on with Musabbir's answer?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `os.path.exists(output_path)` to check if you've already resized the image, if not resize the image. This will prevent overwriting it. Also, as Mark mentioned, "It would seem more natural to me to see if it exists before bothering to open it and resize it."

```
import cv2
import glob
import os

def img_reshape(img_file):
    file_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(img_file))[0]
    output_path = f"{file_name}_resized.jpg"
    if os.path.exists(output_path):
        print(f"{output_path} >>> already exists! thus not changing")
        return 0
    else:
        image = cv2.imread(str(img_file), 1)
        resized_image = cv2.resize(image, (int(image.shape[1]/2), int(image.shape[0]/2)))
        print(f"{output_path} >>> resizing image to this path")
        return cv2.imwrite(output_path, img=resized_image)


def main():
    for files in glob.glob("*.jpg"):
        img_reshape(files)

main()
```

Output after two runs on two sample images:

```
mock_attack_1_resized_resized.jpg >>> already exists! thus not changing
mock_attack_2_resized_resized.jpg >>> already exists! thus not changing
mock_attack_2_resized_resized_resized.jpg >>> resizing image to this path
mock_attack_1_resized_resized_resized.jpg >>> resizing image to this path
mock_attack_2_resized.jpg >>> already exists! thus not changing
mock_attack_1_resized.jpg >>> already exists! thus not changing
```

Comment: yeah, that's obviously a better way. I will modify my answer.